# $g(t)$ on $[p-2,p]$ symmetric about $p-1$ simplify $\int_{p_2}^pg'(t)F(t) dt$

Tags: integration, statistics

I want to simplify $\int_{p-2}^pg'(t)F(t) dt$ where $F(t) = \exp(-t/2)t^{p/2 + j -1}$

Now in the document I am following it says the above integral is equivalent to : $$\int_{p-1}^pg'(t)F_j(t)dt$$ where $F_j(t)= \exp(-t/2)t^{p/2 + j -1} - \exp(\frac{-2(p-1)-t}{2})(2(p-1)-t)^{p/2+j-1}$

I am trying to do it by integration by parts to try and induce the second term but I am struggling.

Any ideas? The paper in question is: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176325640

Comment: If $g$ is even, then $g'$ is odd. You can write any $f(x)=(f(x)+f(-x))/2 + (f(x)-f(-x))/2$ that is with an odd part and an even part. An integral with integrand odd$\times$even over the symmetry point is zero, while odd$\times$odd is an even function.

Comment: @Diger I'll try and write it out but looking at it are you sure it wil give the desired result?

Comment: Yes, to apply the above you may want to substitute $t=p-1+x$ first, do the manipulations and substitute back to $t$, if it helps.

Comment: @Diger Can you help me out a bit? I can get certain terms I need but my $g'(t)$ term does not persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ being symmetric about $p-1$ means $g(p-1+t) = g(p-1-t)$. Or, equivalently, $g(t) = g(2(p-1)-t)$ Taking derivatives shows $g'(t) = -g'(2(p-1)-t)$. Now, split the integral into
\begin{multline}
\int_{p-2}^{p}g'(t)F(t)dt = \int_{p-2}^{p-1}g'(t)F(t)dt + \int_{p-1}^pg'(t)F(t)dt\\ = \int_{p-1}^p g'(2(p-1)-u)F((p-1)-u)du + \int_{p-1}^pg'(t)F(t)dt \\ = -\int_{p-1}^p g'(u)F(2(p-1)-u)du + \int_{p-1}^pg'(t)F(t)dt,
\end{multline}
then combine the integrals to get
$$
\int_{p-2}^{p}g'(t)F(t)dt = \int_{p-1}^p g'(t)\left[F(t) - F(2(p-1)-t)\right]dt
$$
and you can verify that $F_j(t) = F(t) - F(2(p-1)-t)$.